# Maven Release Plugin Fails to release. Svn CHECKOUT failed

Tags: svn, maven-2, release, release-management, maven-release-plugin

Hi I'm trying to use the maven release plug-in on Hudson.
The build succeeds and after then, when hudson tries to release the project, it fails with the following error.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: CHECKOUT of '/svn/projects/!svn/ver/82706/some/path/buildconfig/configuration/pom.xml': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://xx.xxx.xx.xx)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 minutes 17 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Nov xx 12:25:31 CST xxxx
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/88M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

what I'm missing here. I have seen a few articles related to this on stackoverflow.But, they are not related to CHECKOUT.

I think its a problem with SVN, and because of that, maven cannot proceed. The person running the hudson can do the basic SVN commands on the command line.

Any help related to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by asking the person who owned the hudson process to do the release. 
It worked fine then. The problem we have is there is no shared user for hudson. The person who installed it owns it.

When we move to the new hudson box, we have to create a dedicated hudson user.

Answer (score 1):

> The person running the hudson can do the basic SVN commands on the command line.

Does that also mean that the user Hudson is running as (most probably "hudson") can perform the svn commands? If not, you could check that by performing a `sudo su hudson -` and then trying the `mvn release:prepare/perform` commands.

Comment: Waldheinz is correct.  To check this in Windows, you'll need to log into the server as the user that is listed as hudson's 'run as' process.  More than likely, the SVN credentials are not cached for the user that hudson is try to run as.

Comment: This is the scenario. Hudson is running as a service by account X . X can do the basic svn commands. I'm logging in as Y and trying to do the release.